# Horizontal alignment of animateinline and tikz picture (both containing pgfplots)

Tags: beamer, pgfplots, animate

Its basically about two plots, one above, one below. The one above is actually an animation, that plays automatically. The one below is a still plot. The horizontal axis is common to all plots, and this is why I want to align them horizontally, so the x-axis has the same horizontal span in all plots.

Before going on, a "picture" is worth a 1000 words:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

  \pgfmathsetmacro{\PI}{3.141592654}
  \begin{animateinline}[palindrome, autoplay,
                        begin={\begin{tikzpicture}%[show background rectangle]
                               \pgfplotsset{yticklabel style={text width=1.3em,align=right},
                                            xticklabels={,,},
                                            width=0.8\linewidth, height=0.3\textheight,
                                            /tikz/font=\scriptsize, ylabel={$[\text{dB}]$}
                                           }
                              },
                        end={\end{tikzpicture}}
                       ]{2}
    \begin{axis}[name=plot1, ymin=-.2, ymax=1.1, xmin=0, xmax=1]
      \addplot [green!30] coordinates { (.1,.9)(.2,.0)(.3,.0)(.4,.0)(.5,.0)(.6,.0)(.7,.0)(.8,.0)(.9,.0)};
      \addplot [brown!30] coordinates { (.1,.0)(.2,.0)(.3,.0)(.4,.0)(.5,.0)(.6,.0)(.7,.0)(.8,.0)(.9,.8)};
    \end{axis}
    \newframe
    \begin{axis}[ymin=-.2, ymax=1.1, xmin=0, xmax=1]
      \addplot [green!30] coordinates { (.1,.0)(.2,.9)(.3,.0)(.4,.0)(.5,.0)(.6,.0)(.7,.0)(.8,.0)(.9,.0)};
      \addplot [brown!30] coordinates { (.1,.0)(.2,.0)(.3,.0)(.4,.0)(.5,.0)(.6,.0)(.7,.0)(.8,.8)(.9,.0)};
    \end{axis}
    \newframe
    \begin{axis}[ymin=-.2, ymax=1.1, xmin=0, xmax=1]
      \addplot [green!30] coordinates { (.1,.0)(.2,.0)(.3,.9)(.4,.0)(.5,.0)(.6,.0)(.7,.0)(.8,.0)(.9,.0)};
      \addplot [brown!30] coordinates { (.1,.0)(.2,.0)(.3,.0)(.4,.0)(.5,.0)(.6,.0)(.7,.8)(.8,.0)(.9,.0)};
    \end{axis}
    \newframe
    \begin{axis}[ymin=-.2, ymax=1.1, xmin=0, xmax=1]
      \addplot [green!30] coordinates { (.1,.0)(.2,.0)(.3,.0)(.4,.9)(.5,.0)(.6,.0)(.7,.0)(.8,.0)(.9,.0)};
      \addplot [brown!30] coordinates { (.1,.0)(.2,.0)(.3,.0)(.4,.0)(.5,.0)(.6,.8)(.7,.0)(.8,.0)(.9,.0)};
    \end{axis}
    \newframe
    \newframe
    \begin{axis}[ymin=-.2, ymax=1.1, xmin=0, xmax=1]
      \addplot [green!30] coordinates { (.1,.0)(.2,.0)(.3,.0)(.4,.0)(.5,.9)(.6,.0)(.7,.0)(.8,.0)(.9,.0)};
      \addplot [brown!30] coordinates { (.1,.0)(.2,.0)(.3,.0)(.4,.0)(.5,.8)(.6,.0)(.7,.0)(.8,.0)(.9,.0)};
    \end{axis}
    \newframe
    \begin{axis}[ymin=-.2, ymax=1.1, xmin=0, xmax=1]
      \addplot [green!30] coordinates { (.1,.0)(.2,.0)(.3,.0)(.4,.0)(.5,.0)(.6,.9)(.7,.0)(.8,.0)(.9,.0)};
      \addplot [brown!30] coordinates { (.1,.0)(.2,.0)(.3,.0)(.4,.8)(.5,.0)(.6,.0)(.7,.0)(.8,.0)(.9,.0)};
    \end{axis}
    \newframe
    \begin{axis}[ymin=-.2, ymax=1.1, xmin=0, xmax=1]
      \addplot [green!30] coordinates { (.1,.0)(.2,.0)(.3,.0)(.4,.0)(.5,.0)(.6,.0)(.7,.9)(.8,.0)(.9,.0)};
      \addplot [brown!30] coordinates { (.1,.0)(.2,.0)(.3,.8)(.4,.0)(.5,.0)(.6,.0)(.7,.0)(.8,.0)(.9,.0)};
    \end{axis}
    \newframe
    \begin{axis}[ymin=-.2, ymax=1.1, xmin=0, xmax=1]
      \addplot [green!30] coordinates { (.1,.0)(.2,.0)(.3,.0)(.4,.0)(.5,.0)(.6,.0)(.7,.0)(.8,.9)(.9,.0)};
      \addplot [brown!30] coordinates { (.1,.0)(.2,.8)(.3,.0)(.4,.0)(.5,.0)(.6,.0)(.7,.0)(.8,.0)(.9,.0)};
    \end{axis}
    \newframe
    \begin{axis}[ymin=-.2, ymax=1.1, xmin=0, xmax=1]
      \addplot [green!30] coordinates { (.1,.0)(.2,.0)(.3,.0)(.4,.0)(.5,.0)(.6,.0)(.7,.0)(.8,.0)(.9,.9)};
      \addplot [brown!30] coordinates { (.1,.8)(.2,.0)(.3,.0)(.4,.0)(.5,.0)(.6,.0)(.7,.0)(.8,.0)(.9,.0)};
    \end{axis}
  \end{animateinline}

  \vspace{-0.9ex}

  \begin{tikzpicture}%[show background rectangle]
    \pgfplotsset{every axis x label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.10)}, yshift = -6.5pt, anchor=west,},
                 /tikz/font = \scriptsize,
                 width = 0.654\linewidth, height = .4\textheight,
                }
    \begin{axis}[name=plot2, at=(plot1.south), anchor=center,
                 yticklabel style={text width=1.5em,align=left},
                 axis y line* = right,
                 scale only axis,
                 scaled y ticks={real:\PI},
                 ylabel = {\textcolor{gray!50}{Kippwinkel}},
                 ytick scale label code/.code={},
                 ytick distance=\PI/2,
                 yticklabel={\pgfmathparse{round(10*\tick)/10}
                             \pgfmathifisint{\pgfmathresult}{\strut$\pgfmathprintnumber[int detect]{\pgfmathresult}\pi$%
                                                            }{\strut$\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\pi$}
                            },
                 yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/frac,/pgf/number format/frac whole=false, color = gray!50},
                 xmin=0, xmax=1,
                 xlabel = Z-Pixels,
                 xlabel style = {yshift=-2.5ex},
                 xticklabel style={yshift=-2.5ex},
                 xticklabel={\pgfmathparse{round(384*\tick)}\strut$\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}$},
                ]
      \addplot[color=gray!50,smooth] coordinates {(.1,-3)(.2,-1)(.3,1)(.4,3)(.5,1)(.6,-1)(.7,-3)(.8,-1)(.9,1)};
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}[at=(plot2), anchor=center,
                 yticklabel style={text width=1.3em,align=right},
                 axis y line* = left,
                 scale only axis,
                 xmin=0, xmax=1,
                 xlabel = {Tiefe $[\text{mm}]$},
                 ylabel = {\textcolor{red}{Breite $[\mu\text{m}]$}},
                 yticklabel style={color = red},
                ]
      \addplot[color=red,smooth,thick] coordinates {(.1,40)(.2,-35)(.3,30)(.4,-25)(.5,20)(.6,-15)(.7,10)(.8,-5)(.9,0)};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

In order to align the plots I'm playing with the `\pgfplotsset{width=...}` (sadly not the same width for all plots) and `yticklabel style={text width=1.5em,align=left}` directives. But I do not like this method. It is not only less than elegant. It is also hard to automate. In the real world case, the coordinates are generated by a program that collects measurements and computes a model. After the program runs, a script compiles the tex file to produce a sort of a report. But the script does not always comes up with the right distances to fill in the directives.

Is there a more robust way of achieving horizontal alignment?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Without testing it: Try adding `scale only axis=true` and the same `width` to both `axis` environments. That should solve your problem. It that still doesn't work, try absolute `width` values, e.g. `5cm`, instead of relative ones, e.g. `0.5\textwidth`. Maybe you get different `\textwidth`'s in the `animateinline` environment.

Comment: That works! No need to use absolute width values, though. Could you please post your comment as an answer, that I can accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned in [the comment below the question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/368188/h#comment908416_368188) you simply need to add `scale only axis` to "all" `axis` environments and give the same `width` value then.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.14
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
\usepackage{animate}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\PI}{3.141592654}
    \begin{animateinline}[
        palindrome,
        autoplay,
        begin={%
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \pgfplotsset{
                    yticklabel style={text width=1.3em,align=right},
                    % changed to `\empty'
                    xticklabels=\empty,
                    % ---------------------------------------------------------
                    % added `scale only axis' ...
                    scale only axis,
                    % ... and set to the same `width' as below
                    width = 0.65\linewidth,
                    % ---------------------------------------------------------
                    height=0.3\textheight,
                    /tikz/font=\scriptsize,
                    ylabel={$[\text{dB}]$},
                }
        },
        end={\end{tikzpicture}}
    ]{2}
        \begin{axis}[name=plot1, ymin=-.2, ymax=1.1, xmin=0, xmax=1]
            \addplot [green!30] coordinates { (.1,.9)(.2,.0)(.3,.0)(.4,.0)(.5,.0)(.6,.0)(.7,.0)(.8,.0)(.9,.0)};
            \addplot [brown!30] coordinates { (.1,.0)(.2,.0)(.3,.0)(.4,.0)(.5,.0)(.6,.0)(.7,.0)(.8,.0)(.9,.8)};
        \end{axis}
            \newframe
        \begin{axis}[ymin=-.2, ymax=1.1, xmin=0, xmax=1]
            \addplot [green!30] coordinates { (.1,.0)(.2,.9)(.3,.0)(.4,.0)(.5,.0)(.6,.0)(.7,.0)(.8,.0)(.9,.0)};
            \addplot [brown!30] coordinates { (.1,.0)(.2,.0)(.3,.0)(.4,.0)(.5,.0)(.6,.0)(.7,.0)(.8,.8)(.9,.0)};
        \end{axis}
            \newframe
        \begin{axis}[ymin=-.2, ymax=1.1, xmin=0, xmax=1]
            \addplot [green!30] coordinates { (.1,.0)(.2,.0)(.3,.9)(.4,.0)(.5,.0)(.6,.0)(.7,.0)(.8,.0)(.9,.0)};
            \addplot [brown!30] coordinates { (.1,.0)(.2,.0)(.3,.0)(.4,.0)(.5,.0)(.6,.0)(.7,.8)(.8,.0)(.9,.0)};
        \end{axis}
            \newframe
        \begin{axis}[ymin=-.2, ymax=1.1, xmin=0, xmax=1]
            \addplot [green!30] coordinates { (.1,.0)(.2,.0)(.3,.0)(.4,.9)(.5,.0)(.6,.0)(.7,.0)(.8,.0)(.9,.0)};
            \addplot [brown!30] coordinates { (.1,.0)(.2,.0)(.3,.0)(.4,.0)(.5,.0)(.6,.8)(.7,.0)(.8,.0)(.9,.0)};
        \end{axis}
            \newframe
            \newframe
        \begin{axis}[ymin=-.2, ymax=1.1, xmin=0, xmax=1]
            \addplot [green!30] coordinates { (.1,.0)(.2,.0)(.3,.0)(.4,.0)(.5,.9)(.6,.0)(.7,.0)(.8,.0)(.9,.0)};
            \addplot [brown!30] coordinates { (.1,.0)(.2,.0)(.3,.0)(.4,.0)(.5,.8)(.6,.0)(.7,.0)(.8,.0)(.9,.0)};
        \end{axis}
            \newframe
        \begin{axis}[ymin=-.2, ymax=1.1, xmin=0, xmax=1]
            \addplot [green!30] coordinates { (.1,.0)(.2,.0)(.3,.0)(.4,.0)(.5,.0)(.6,.9)(.7,.0)(.8,.0)(.9,.0)};
            \addplot [brown!30] coordinates { (.1,.0)(.2,.0)(.3,.0)(.4,.8)(.5,.0)(.6,.0)(.7,.0)(.8,.0)(.9,.0)};
        \end{axis}
            \newframe
        \begin{axis}[ymin=-.2, ymax=1.1, xmin=0, xmax=1]
            \addplot [green!30] coordinates { (.1,.0)(.2,.0)(.3,.0)(.4,.0)(.5,.0)(.6,.0)(.7,.9)(.8,.0)(.9,.0)};
            \addplot [brown!30] coordinates { (.1,.0)(.2,.0)(.3,.8)(.4,.0)(.5,.0)(.6,.0)(.7,.0)(.8,.0)(.9,.0)};
        \end{axis}
            \newframe
        \begin{axis}[ymin=-.2, ymax=1.1, xmin=0, xmax=1]
          \addplot [green!30] coordinates { (.1,.0)(.2,.0)(.3,.0)(.4,.0)(.5,.0)(.6,.0)(.7,.0)(.8,.9)(.9,.0)};
          \addplot [brown!30] coordinates { (.1,.0)(.2,.8)(.3,.0)(.4,.0)(.5,.0)(.6,.0)(.7,.0)(.8,.0)(.9,.0)};
        \end{axis}
            \newframe
        \begin{axis}[ymin=-.2, ymax=1.1, xmin=0, xmax=1]
            \addplot [green!30] coordinates { (.1,.0)(.2,.0)(.3,.0)(.4,.0)(.5,.0)(.6,.0)(.7,.0)(.8,.0)(.9,.9)};
            \addplot [brown!30] coordinates { (.1,.8)(.2,.0)(.3,.0)(.4,.0)(.5,.0)(.6,.0)(.7,.0)(.8,.0)(.9,.0)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{animateinline}

        \vspace{-0.9ex}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pgfplotsset{
            every axis x label/.style={
                at={(ticklabel* cs:1.10)},
                yshift = -6.5pt,
                anchor=west,
            },
            /tikz/font = \scriptsize,
            width = 0.65\linewidth,
            height = .4\textheight,
            % -----------------------------------------------------------------
            % added `scale only axis'
            scale only axis,
            % -----------------------------------------------------------------
        }
        \begin{axis}[
            name=plot2,
            at=(plot1.south),
            anchor=center,
            yticklabel style={text width=1.5em,align=left},
            axis y line* = right,
            scaled y ticks={real:\PI},
            ylabel = {\textcolor{gray!50}{Kippwinkel}},
            ytick scale label code/.code={},
            ytick distance=\PI/2,
            yticklabel={%
                \pgfmathparse{round(10*\tick)/10}%
                \pgfmathifisint{\pgfmathresult}{%
                    \strut$\pgfmathprintnumber[int detect]{\pgfmathresult}\pi$%
                }{%
                    \strut$\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\pi$%
                }
            },
            yticklabel style={
                /pgf/number format/frac,
                /pgf/number format/frac whole=false,
                color = gray!50,
            },
            xmin=0,
            xmax=1,
            xlabel = Z-Pixels,
            xlabel style = {yshift=-2.5ex},
            xticklabel style={yshift=-2.5ex},
            xticklabel={%
                \pgfmathparse{round(384*\tick)}\strut$\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}$%
            },
        ]
            \addplot[color=gray!50,smooth] coordinates {(.1,-3)(.2,-1)(.3,1)(.4,3)(.5,1)(.6,-1)(.7,-3)(.8,-1)(.9,1)};
        \end{axis}
        \begin{axis}[
            at=(plot2),
            anchor=center,
            yticklabel style={text width=1.3em,align=right},
            axis y line* = left,
            xmin=0, xmax=1,
            xlabel = {Tiefe $[\text{mm}]$},
            ylabel = {\textcolor{red}{Breite $[\mu\text{m}]$}},
            yticklabel style={color = red},
        ]
            \addplot[color=red,smooth,thick] coordinates {(.1,40)(.2,-35)(.3,30)(.4,-25)(.5,20)(.6,-15)(.7,10)(.8,-5)(.9,0)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: @Pablo : There is one blank frame in the animation. Is it on purpose?

Comment: Ähm, I din't notice the blank frame. No, if it is there, I do not want it. Is it because there are nine frames and I'm asking two of them per second? I wrote "2" in the example to make it simple. If this is an issue, I would like to know more details about it. Thank you!

Comment: @Stefan. Thank you for the additional embedded tips.

Comment: @AlexG. Ohh, I see the problem. There are two consecutive `\newframe` commands. That was a typo.